# Python remove data from HTML file based on duplicate value

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I would like to know how to remove results from my `html` file based on a duplicate value.

The below sample `html` from a generated report has duplicate numbers in the `NAME2` line. `'12345'`, because of this I would like to remove the entire record.

The trick is that the duplicate values will be dynamic but will always be in the same line '`NAME2`'. When I say remove the entire record, in the below example we have a duplicate on line '`NAME2`' as a result I would like to remove everything `('NAME1', 'NAME2', 'NAME3', 'NAME4')` from the file.

I have included below a code sample and also my expected result.

```
<SAMPLE CODE>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<pre>
<font face="courier new" size=-4>                                                

NAME1......... DOUG
NAME2........... 12345
NAME3... BILL
NAME4...... BOB

NAME1......... ALLAN
NAME2........... 12345
NAME3... MITCHELL
NAME4...... TOM

</font>
</pre>
</body>
</html>

<EXPECTED RESULT>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<pre>
<font face="courier new" size=-4>                                                

NAME1......... DOUG
NAME2........... 12345
NAME3... BILL
NAME4...... BOB



</font>
</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: where is your expected result?

Comment: sorry, I have edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script will compare all `NAME2` values and if they are equal, only first group is left in HTML document (maybe the regexes need to adjust to match real data in your documents):

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html_data = '''
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<pre>
<font face="courier new" size=-4>

NAME1......... DOUG
NAME2........... 12345
NAME3... BILL
NAME4...... BOB

NAME1......... ALLAN
NAME2........... 12345
NAME3... MITCHELL
NAME4...... TOM

</font>
</pre>
</body>
</html>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_data, 'html.parser')
vals = set(re.findall(r'NAME2\.+\s*(.*)\s*', soup.font.text))
if len(vals) == 1:
    soup.font.string = re.search(r'.*?NAME1.*?\n\n', soup.font.text, flags=re.S).group(0)

print(soup.prettify())
```

Prints:

```
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
  <pre>
<font face="courier new" size="-4">

NAME1......... DOUG
NAME2........... 12345
NAME3... BILL
NAME4...... BOB

</font>
</pre>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, could you explain a little further please. So *italics*
`vals = set(re.findall(r'Entity Id.\.+\s*(.*)\s*', soup.font.text))`

Comment: @JamesCook This is regex that will match value after `Entity Id..... `. See more here: https://regex101.com/r/hWVESJ/1

Comment: Great, thanks. Fantastic tool. Im still getting duplicate values return after running script. `soup.font.string = re.search(r'.*?NAME1.*?\n\n', soup.font.text, flags=re.S).group(0)`

Comment: @JamesCook Can you edit your question and put there document where you get duplicates?

Comment: Sorry I posted the last comment before I finished typing. The data im working with is sensitive and I need to keep it private. I think my issue is the regex in line `soup.font.string = re.search(r'.*?NAME1.*?\n\n', soup.font.text, flags=re.S).group(0)` my data is actually alphanumeric, so as you said I think I need to adjust the regex in that line?

Comment: @JamesCook Yes, you need to adjust the regex probably. You can use the Regex101 tool and make the changes there. Then copy the regex to the script.

Comment: Could you please explain this line `soup.font.string = re.search(r'.*?NAME1.*?\n\n', soup.font.text, flags=re.S).group(0)` a little further? I have tried a differant regex but Im not getting the desired result. Also if I use `print(vals)` it returns all of the numbers relating to `NAME2` but without duplicates?

Comment: @JamesCook `vals` is of type `set`, so there aren't duplicates. If length of this set is 1, it means that there is duplicate and then the regex ``.*?NAME1.*?\n\n`` will get first group from the `<font>` tag. Then replace the content of `<font>` tag with this group.

Comment: Suppose I had multiple groups (hundreds) in the font tag. Could I manipulate your code to remove the groups that included a duplicate.  Example of HTML below    `<SAMPLE CODE>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<pre>
<font face="courier new" size=-4>                                                

NAME1......... DOUG
NAME2........... 12345
NAME3... BILL
NAME4...... BOB

NAME1......... ALLAN
NAME2........... 12345
NAME3... MITCHELL
NAME4...... TOM
NAME1......... DOUG
NAME2........... 12345
NAME3... BILL
NAME4...... BOB

</font>
</pre>
</body>
</html>  `

Comment: @JamesCook To not clutter the comment section here I recommend to open a new question here on StackOverflow. I can answer your question there.

Comment: Sure, Will do.. Thank you

Comment: FYI. I have created new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63332247/remove-text-groups-from-html-document