# Remove text groups from html document

Tags: html, beautifulsoup

I have the below "SAMPLE CODE" from a html document. My intention is the "EXPECTED RESULT" I would like the script to run through the document and check for duplicates. If it returns true and and duplicates are present based on "NAME2" line then I would like the script to remove the entire "name group" but leave 1 group.
The script I have so far removes all groups if a duplicate is found and keeps the first....

```
<SAMPLE CODE>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<pre>
<font face="courier new" size=-4>

##Name Group (Name1,Name2,Name3,Name4)
NAME1....... DOUG
NAME2....... 12345
NAME3....... BILL
NAME4....... BOB

NAME1....... ALLAN
NAME2....... 12345
NAME3....... MITCHELL
NAME4....... TOM   
         
NAME1....... CRAIG
NAME2....... 12345
NAME3....... SIMON
NAME4....... ANDREW

NAME1....... GARY
NAME2....... 65897
NAME3....... OLIVER
NAME4....... MICHAEL

</font>
</pre>
</body>
</html>  


<EXPECTED RESULT>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<pre>
<font face="courier new" size=-4>                                                

NAME1....... DOUG
NAME2....... 12345
NAME3....... BILL
NAME4....... BOB

NAME1....... GARY
NAME2....... 65897
NAME3....... OLIVER
NAME4....... MICHAEL


</font>
</pre>
</body>
</html>

import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html_data = '''
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<pre>
<font face="courier new" size=-4>

NAME1......... DOUG
NAME2........... 12345
NAME3... BILL
NAME4...... BOB

NAME1......... ALLAN
NAME2........... 12345
NAME3... MITCHELL
NAME4...... TOM

</font>
</pre>
</body>
</html>
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_data, 'html.parser')
vals = set(re.findall(r'NAME2\.+\s*(.*)\s*', soup.font.text))
if len(vals) == 1:
    soup.font.string = re.search(r'.*?NAME1.*?\n\n', soup.font.text, flags=re.S).group(0)

print(soup.prettify()`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a big fan of regex, especially not in html, so I would suggest doing something like this:

```
data = soup.select_one('font')
targets = data.text.replace('NAME1','xxxNAME1').split('xxx')
groups = [target.strip().split('\n') for target in targets[1:]]
for group in groups[1:]:
    if group[1] == groups[groups.index(group)-1][1]:
        groups.remove(group)
new_ts = '\n'
for group in groups:
    new_ts += '\n'.join(group)+'\n\n'
data.string.replace_with(new_ts)
soup
```

Output is your expected output.

Comment: thanks Jack, worked perfectly on my sample code. Question, will this only work once when it finds a duplicate on `NAME2` ? To be more specific, the actual `html` I am working with has 1600 + pages of data. So there will be other duplicates with different numbers in `NAME 2` line

Comment: Answered my own question, it will.. thanks again Jack

Comment: Sorry, another question. The only differance between the `html` i supplied in my `Sample Code` and my actual `html` is the name of the line. My `html` is named something else. It should just be a matter of replacing the names in `targets = data.text.replace('NAME1','xxxNAME1').split('xxx')`?

Comment: @JamesCook I believe so.